# python: piping loop error into list without interrupting loop

Tags: python, loops

I am extracting information from a large number of files using a loop iterating through a file list. Some of the files are corrupted and the operation cannot be done. this causes a 'PackageNotFoundError:'

The error is to be expected.
Question: How can I log the index of the bad file and the loop to continue?

My code

```
for c in targets_in_dir:

    document = Document(c)
    table = document.tables[2]

    data = []

    keys = None
    for i, row in enumerate(table.rows):
        text = (cell.text for cell in row.cells)

        if i == 0:
            keys = tuple(text)
            continue
        row_data = dict(zip(keys, text))
        data.append(row_data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like the below

```
targets_in_dir = ['A', 'B', 'C']
for idx, c in enumerate(targets_in_dir):
    try:
        # your logic goes here
        if c == 'B':
            raise Exception('Something is wrong ..')
        else:
            print(c)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Target {c} at index {idx} raised an exception')
```

output

```
A
Target B at index 1 raised an exception
C
```

Comment: basically I have to predefine the errors that occur or does the raise Exception happen automatically?

Comment: @NimrodEts - you dont have to define it. The exception will be raised and the `except ` block will "catch" it